# codesleeve asset pipeline not compiling or concatenating except on local

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I am using Codesleeve Asset Pipeline in Laravel 4 to serve my css and js files.

Unfortunately it does not want to compile bootstrap in a staging environment.

This is the config:

```
'paths' => array(

    'app/assets/javascripts',
    'app/assets/stylesheets',
    'app/assets/images',
    'lib/assets/javascripts',
    'lib/assets/stylesheets',
    'lib/assets/images',
    'provider/assets/javascripts',
    'provider/assets/stylesheets',

    'provider/assets/images',
    'vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/',
    'vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/',

),
```

Those 3 lines are the only ones changed.

On my local instance it works fine, I get one css file including all of bootstrap and my own stuff, and one js file with jquery and the bootstrap plugins I asked for.

But on the staging server, I get this:

```
    <link href="http://website.net/assets/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://website.net/assets/application.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://website.net/assets/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://website.net/assets/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/button.js" ></script>
<script src="http://website.net/assets/vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js" ></script>
<script src="http://website.net/assets/application.js" ></script>
```

I think that the asset pipeline is not even trying to concatenate or compile anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the minifier was barfing on bootstrap 3's css, and not producing the file. However no error was thrown.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your staging server on the config asset-pipeline so it also compiles on this stage.